# Conditional Formatting with wildcards in EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

i´m trying to aply a format to cells that contains the **"SUBTOTAL "** Word, this is my code:

```
ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress(2,1,tam,40);

string _statement = "$A2=\"SUBTOTAL \"";

var _cond1 = hoja.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond1.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
_cond1.Style.Font.Color.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
_cond1.Formula = _statement;
```

And Works fine if the cell only contains this Word, but in all cases(except 1) the value of the cell will be **"SUBTOTAL "** + more text.

So i wold like to know if it´s posible to use wildcards or something similar to an SQL `like` statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("SUBTOTAL ", $A2))
```

if case sensitive

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SUBTOTAL ", $A2))
```

if case insensitive.

The functions Search and Find returns the index of first occurrence of the searched word, of #VALUE!, if nothing found. IsNumber decides, if it is number or #VALUE!

Comment: Thanks. Works for me